# Custom UI-Bootstrap Buttons / Buttongroup

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create some custom buttons or rather a custom button group for my page but i have no clue where to edit the button. I want to change things like:

- active/normal state
- font
- text/background color
- border

> ```
> <div class="btn-group" id="category-switch">
> <label class="btn btn-custom" ng-model="Test.radioModel" uib-btn-radio="Left" id="label-critic">left</label>
> <label class="btn btn-custom" ng-model="Test.radioModel" uib-btn-radio="Middle" id="label-general">middke</label>
> <label class="btn btn-custom" ng-model="Test.radioModel" uib-btn-radio="Right" id="label-support">right</label>
> </div>
> ```

---

I first tried to use some CSS to format my buttons

(in .less format)

```
#category-switch{
            padding-top: 48px;
            padding-left: 17px;
            background: @navbar-background;
            border: 1px soild black;

            #label-critic{
                width: 85px;
                height: 26px;
                padding-top: 2px;
                background: @navbar-background;
                border: 1px soild black;
            }

            #label-general{
                width: 91px;
                height: 26px;
                padding-top: 2px;
                background: @navbar-background;
            }

            #label-support{
                width: 90px;
                height: 26px;
                padding-top: 2px;
                background: @navbar-background;
            }
        }

        .custom{
            border: 1px soild black;
        }
```

---

After this attempt I tried to copy a default button and edit the copy. I named it custom

**Edits in butons.less (Default bootstrap less file)**

```
.btn-custom {
  .button-variant(@btn-danger-color; @btn-danger-bg; @btn-danger-border);
}
```

**Edits in variables.less**

```
//CUSTOM BUTTON BGE
@btn-custom-color:               #fff;
@btn-custom-bg:                  #606060;
@btn-custom-border:              black;
```

This also doesn´t work. In the end it looked liked this, which is absolutely not the result i wanted.

[image]

---

So the question is:
**HOW can I customize my ui-bootstrap button-group/buttons ?**

---

**EDIT**

It seems that my CSS/less works partially due to changes of the size and adding of the button. This changes are applied correctly to my button but changes of the border/color aren´t applied.

Answer (score 0):

I already did some changes on the default layout of a bootstrap button. I always used css (or less). Have in mind that css always overrides styles which were set before. Therefore make sure to load your custom file last or add

> !important

to all of your css styles to be sure they'll be accepcted. E.g.:

```
#label-critic{
                width: 85px !important;
                height: 26px !important;
                padding-top: 2px !important;
                background: @navbar-background !important;
                border: 1px soild black !important;
```

Does this help? If not what's the problem? Won't your own css styles apply or do they just look weird? If they look weird it's a problem with your styling itself rather than bootstrap buttons.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems that not all but some changes like width, height or padding are applied.So I guess I have to change the color, font and background of the buttons or the group in another way I did. I would say the CSS applies partially and it looks weird. Your idea with `!important` dosn´t seems to work in `less`

Comment: @JohnDizzle I had the semicolons at the wrong position, they have to be at the end of the line for sure. Less does work with !important. Sorry for the mistake, I updated my answer to correct the issue.